# Custom RSpec routing matcher for all four HTTP verbs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, rails-routing, matcher

I'm writing a RSpec test suite of our routes for a rather large Rails 3 application. Many of the routes use "MATCH", but none of them should, especially since we'll have to rewrite them as we transition to Rails 4.

Most of my `it` blocks look something like this:

```
  it "with /comments/account/100" do
    expect(get("comments/account/100")).to    route_to("comments#list", :account_id => "100")
    expect(post("comments/account/100")).to   route_to("comments#list", :account_id => "100")
    expect(put("comments/account/100")).to    route_to("comments#list", :account_id => "100")
    expect(delete("comments/account/100")).to route_to("comments#list", :account_id => "100")
  end
```

It seems a bit, non-DRY, to have to write an endless number of blocks like that. I'd like to have a matcher that looks something like this:

```
expect(match_all_verbs("/comments/accounts/100")).to route_to("comments#list", :account_id => "100")
```

**EDIT: Final working version, thanks to Steven:**

```
def match_all_verbs(path, method, options = {})
  [:get, :post, :put, :delete].each do |verb|
    expect(send(verb, path)).to route_to(method, options)
  end
end
```

I added an `options` hash so I could pass params to the routes. Everything seems to be working fine.

And for fun, I made a `match_no_verbs` to test the `.to_not be_routable` matcher combo:

```
def match_no_verbs(path, method, options = {})
  [:get, :post, :put, :delete].each do |verb|
    expect(send(verb, path)).to_not route_to(method, options)
  end
end
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec custom matchers take a single value per the [documentation](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Matchers), so your formal parameter `values` is not getting defined and your reference to it in the body of your matcher fails.

Rather than a custom matcher, whose intent is to specify what equality means and how to display errors for a given type of object, I think you'd want to use some kind of helper which iterates over the verbs and generates the appropriate `expect` calls.

For example, you could use (not tested):

```
def match_all_verbs(path, method)
  [:get, :post, :put:, :delete].each do |verb|
    expect(send(verb, path)).to route_to(method)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. That's (almost) exactly what I needed. Much simpler than what I was trying. See my edit up top.